# Laravel Nova Table Listing Delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

[image: Nova Listing]

As per imange above, I current maintain a laravel nova website, i have tried to find where it declare/enable the "Force Delete Selected" but I cant find it, I only able to find forceDeleted() function inside App\Observers. Anyone know how to change this? I want to change "Force Delete Selected" to soft delete.

Answer (score 0):

To find the related [policy](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/authorization.html#policies), you can search for it within the appropriate context. For instance, if the resource in question is a user, you should look for it in the `UserPolicy` file located in the `Policies` directory.

If you are able to execute a force-delete action, this indicates that the `forceDelete` method has already been declared within the appropriate context.

If Nova detects a policy has been registered for the model, it will automatically check that policy's relevant authorization methods before performing their respective actions, such as:

- `viewAny`
- `view`
- `create`
- `update`
- `replicate`
- `delete`
- `restore`
- `forceDelete`